# Detect debian version in "rules" package file

Tags: debian, packaging, deb

I'm trying to merge build configuration for different version of debian (as it's hard to maintain when separated).

There are only a few minor changes, but the main issue I run into is that I don't know how to detect the current version of debian inside of the "rules" file.

Do I just parse the `/etc/debian_version` file, or is there a more sensible approach?

Comment: I hope you also change the version of the package as well, as what you're trying to do will cause the same .deb filename being generated on different Debian versions that contains different versions of the package! Utter confusion lies ahead!  It may sound like a good idea but trust me, in the future you will regret this.

Comment: @wurtel I'm already doing that. It's always `packageName_packageVersion+debX_architecture.deb`

Comment: what do you mean by "debian version"?  do you mean a particular stable release (and/or subsequent point releases)?  or a daily snapshot of testing or unstable?   IMO the version number of debian itself isn't particularly useful or significant....but package versions are.

Comment: @cas Actually it's the other way around. Different versions of debian have different directory layouts. Debian 6 had packages with libraries in the following format: `/usr/PACKAGE/lib`, Debian 7 had `/usr/lib/PACKAGE`, Debian 8 has `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/PACKAGE`.

Comment: That's got nothing to do with the version of debian, and everything to do with the versions of the packages that have those files and directories.  You'll get exactly the same result if you install packages from "Debian 8" onto a "Debian 6" system.  Most people (i.e. those running 'stable') only see such changes when they upgrade to the next stable release.  people running 'testing' or 'sid' see the changes much earlier.

Comment: @cas No, it has nothing to do with the version of the package, because the same version of package, built for different versions of Debian will have different directory structures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `/usr/bin/lsb_release` for that.

`lsb_release -rs` is probably what you want.

Comment: Then he'd have to have `Depends: lsb-release` because lsb-release is an optional package.

Comment: @cas Ah, yes, that is correct.